# How to use different plugins on different entry in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

For example , I have two entries a.js and b.js; a.js use A plugin and b.js use B plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you will have to use multiple configurations (two in your case).
Instead of exporting a configuration, you can export an array of configuration.

```
module.exports = [
  {
    entry: 'myappA.js',
    plugins: [new MyPluginA()],
    ...
  },
  {
    entry: 'myappB.js',
    plugins: [new MyPluginB()],
    ...
  }
]
```

You can find more information on the official documentation:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations